# Facet free scale "y" dont work with double axis

Tags: r, ggplot2, limit, facet-wrap

I am try to overlay 2 graphs, I used free Y scale in facet to display properly the data:

```
set.seed(123)

df <-data.frame(
    var1 = 15000 + c(0, cumsum(runif(49, -10, 10))),
    var2 = rnorm(100, 10, 1),
    cate= factor(LETTERS[1:4]),
    date = seq(as.Date("2002-01-01"), by="1 month", length.out=100))

df$var1[df$cate=="A"]=rnorm(25, 10,1)

 ggplot(df, aes(x=date))+ 
 geom_line(data=df, aes(y=var1, color="red"), size=1)+
 theme(legend.position="")+ 
 facet_wrap(facets = ~cate, scale="free_y") +
 theme(
         axis.text.x = element_text(
         angle = 45, face = "bold", hjust = 0.85, 
         color="black", size=11))

 ggplot(df, aes(x=date))+ 
 geom_line(data=df, aes(y=var2), size=1, color="blue")+
 theme(legend.position="")+ 
 facet_wrap(facets = ~cate, scale="free_y") +
 theme(
         axis.text.x = element_text(
         angle = 45, face = "bold", hjust = 0.85, 
         color="black", size=11))
```

[image: How overlay?]

I tried to overlay both graph using a second axis. I used a free Y scale using facet. Lamentably my first axis (left side) dont display properly the data or variation because this problem (limits of left side are not ok).

I made some adjust (multiply) the second axis to get the right scale. to do this I got the max value from var1 and var2, acording:

https://whatalnk.github.io/r-tips/ggplot2-secondary-y-axis.nb.html

```
summary(df)

      var1                var2        cate        date           
 Min.   :    7.642   Min.   : 6.962   A:25   Min.   :2002-01-01  
 1st Qu.:11227.279   1st Qu.: 9.170   B:25   1st Qu.:2004-01-24  
 Median :14994.614   Median : 9.965   C:25   Median :2006-02-15  
 Mean   :11254.102   Mean   : 9.888   D:25   Mean   :2006-02-14  
 3rd Qu.:15008.424   3rd Qu.:10.579          3rd Qu.:2008-03-08  
 Max.   :15035.587   Max.   :12.367          Max.   :2010-04-01  
> 


 ggplot(df, aes(x=date))+ 
 geom_line(data=df, aes(y=var1, color="blue"), size=1)+
 geom_line(data=df, aes(y=var2*15035/12.367, color="red"), size=1) +
 theme(legend.position="")+ 
 facet_wrap(facets = ~cate, scale="free_y") +
 theme(
         axis.text.x = element_text(
         angle = 45, face = "bold", hjust = 0.85, 
         color="black", size=11))+
 scale_y_continuous(
    sec.axis = sec_axis(~ .*12.367/15035, name="var2"))
```

[image: example]

**EDIT: **

If I dont multiply I get this:

```
 ggplot(df, aes(x=date))+ 
 geom_line(data=df, aes(y=var1, color="blue"), size=1)+
 geom_line(data=df, aes(y=var2, color="red"), size=1) +
 theme(legend.position="")+ 
 facet_wrap(facets = ~cate, scale="free_y") +
 theme(
         axis.text.x = element_text(
         angle = 45, face = "bold", hjust = 0.85, 
         color="black", size=11))+
 scale_y_continuous(
    sec.axis = sec_axis(~ ., name="var2"))
```

[image: Not multiply]

Comment: I don't know that I understand completely. Your `var1` and `var2` for `cate=="A"` are on the same order-of-magnitude, so multiplying `var2*15070/12.150` is producing a much larger number than `var1` in that facet. `var1` in cate's B, C, and D range from 14996 to 15070, whereas in A it ranges from 7.5 to 11.6. This by itself is a challenge to preserve scale and such between facets, I'm not sure how it could be any different.

Comment: Yes I agree, facet "A" is ok if I dont multiply, lines looks ok, but the other none display properly var1 or var2. But if I add scales= "free_y" I supose that scales are differents for each facet, then I should see the data properly in each facet. I add this plot, only var1

Comment: I guess the point that needs to be resolved is not (yet) how to free the scales, it's what you intent to show when you data is clearly not compatible with keeping the visual perspective with different orders of magnitude. If possible, it would help immensely if you manually create an image of what you expect this sample data to actually look like (whether with `ggplot`, base `plot`, or just a napkin-sketch).

Comment: Thanks I add expected results.

Comment: That provides the necessary clarity. Unfortunately, `sec_axis` requires that all facets have the same expansion and secondary scales. When you have disparate scales like that, one option would be to break it up by `cate` and use `patchwork` to combine multiple plots. This is certainly not an ideal solution (and I hope somebody else will find what I have been unable to find), but if you need them to be side-by-side and the values range like that, at least `patchwork` will approximate things (with some elbow-grease).